# Access properties of a UITableViewCell from the UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm coding an app that has a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`. The `UITableView` uses prototype cells, which inside of each one is a `UITextField`. The view, as you may guess, is a form that the user's going to fill in.

When the user clicks a button in the UI, an event should be fired where all the text values from each one of the `UITextField`s that are being displayed is collected so the data can be sent to the server.

I'm having trouble accessing the cell's `UITextField` property so I can grab the text value.

Part of my code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIDentifier = @"Cell";
    AddCardCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIDentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AddCardCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIDentifier];
    }

    cell.campoTextField.placeholder = [placeholders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.tituloLabel.text = [titulosCampos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

The setup of my data source:

```
titulosCampos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Nombre", @"Correo", nil];
placeholders = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Oscar Swanros", @"dev@swanros.com", nil];
```

Comment: is your requirement to get all the cells campoTextField's text into one array while pressing on a button?

Comment: Each text field "being displayed" - are you hoping to get the text from just the visible cells?

Comment: I want to get the text from all textFields when pressing a button, not just from the ones visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the text which is stored in all cells `campoTextField`, then use this code.....

```
NSMutableArray *titulosCampoTextArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < titulosCampos.count; i++) {

    AddCardCell *cell = (AddCardCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    [titulosCampoTextArray addObject:cell.campoTextField.text];
}
NSLog(@"Data in titulosCampoText array %@",titulosCampoTextArray);
```

hope this will helps you..:-)

Comment: This code is in the method that's going to be fired when the user presses the button?

Comment: Forget it. This worked like magic. Love you, seriously. Thank's very much :)

Comment: @OscarSwanros - That's fine...:-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `AddCardCell` is the text field's delegate. The best approach for this is for your cell class to declare a delegate protocol of its own. Your view controller would then be the cell's delegate. Your cell should then implement the text field's delegate method to detect when the text has changed. Then the cell should tell its delegate that there is new text. The text should be one of the parameters in the delegate method. Your view controller would implement this cell delegate method. The view controller would then update the data model with the updated text.

When the button is tapped, the text from all of the cells will already be in the data model.